# C# Drag and Drop bitmap image from ListView with transparency

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, drag-and-drop, clipboard

I'm building an Excel-DNA XLL and one of the forms allows the user to drag and drop an image from a ListView into an Excel worksheet (or any other Microsoft Office document). While this seemed easy enough, my first solution lost the transparency.

```
string name = myListView.FocusedItem.ImageKey;
var image = myListView.LargeImageList.Images[name];
myListView.DoDragDrop(image, DragDropEffects.All);
```

I managed to get Copy and Paste working by saving the image to MemoryStream in PNG format and using Clipboard.SetData(). I took this a step further Pasted the image into the DoDragDrop method. This works.

```
string name = myListView.FocusedItem.ImageKey;
var image = myListView.LargeImageList.Images[name];
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    Clipboard.SetData("PNG", stream);
    myListView.DoDragDrop(Clipboard.GetDataObject(), DragDropEffects.All);
}
```

I'd rather not alter the Clipboard contents but, when I try to avoid it, the data refuses to Drop.

```
string name = myListView.FocusedItem.ImageKey;
var image = myListView.LargeImageList.Images[name];
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    IDataObject data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
    myListView.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.All);
}
```

I'm convinced this has something to do with the memory stream, that the Copy and Paste perhaps forces the entire stream be read. I really have no idea but either way, I can't seem to find a workaround for using the Clipboard.

Comment: This is not really an Excel or Excel-DNA question. It might help to tag as Winforms instead.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure if the problem is dropping to Excel or dragging from the form but that's unlikely to do with Excel-DNA either way.